# SharePoint 2010 - WebParts only working when debugging

Tags: 2010, web-part, debugging

So basically here's my question, I got a SharePoint 2010 website working with some web parts but the web parts only work when I'm debugging the project, when I'm not it just says that the web part wasn't found in the gallery. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you deployed your WSP with Web part?

Comment: Hey @Ram I'm fairly new at Sharepoint, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Step 1- Create WSP
Step 2- Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath c:\Name_of_Wsp.wsp
Step 3- Install-SPSolution -Identity Name_of_Wsp.wsp.wsp  -WebApplication WebApplication -GACDeployment
E.g WebApplication = http://pc10:8181
Then check your Web part is came in the Web part gallery, if yes then add it on page and check it.
Is your web part is custom ? With CSOM or SSOM?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ram, but I went with P S solution and it worked out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because, when you stop debugging the solution get retracted from webapplication.

Deploy the solution and you will find webparts in gallery.